# How to display a single row of data from cloud firestore using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to display specific data elements returned from a cloud firestore function, on a vue.js page. Using logging I can verify that the cloud function is being called, and the data is being returned from it.

I saw a post that was similar to my need. However, the solution "let _this = this" is already something I've been trying. I've done this successfully in a b-table tag. I have yet to do this successfully for a single row of data (in this case it will be a Profile page where the user can edit their profile).

I tried assigning individual fields (such as this.lastName), as well as in an object (such as this.user = user, then assigning v-model="user.lastName").

```
<template>
  <LoadingScreen v-if="isLoading" />
  <div v-else>
    <div id="profileContainer">
      <div class="profileSection">
        <h4>Last name</h4>
        <b-form-input v-model="lastName" type="text" class="profileItem"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
data() {
      return {
        API: API,
        isLoading: false,
        firstName: "test",
        lastName: "",
        user: [],
        errorMessage: "",
        shouldShowError: false
      }
    },
```

```
    setup() {
      let self = this;
      **console.log("In Setup", this);**

      self.isLoading = true;
      API.getCurrentUser()
        .then(user => {
          **console.log("results:", user.lastName);**
          self.isLoading = false;
          self.firstName = user.firstName;
          self.lastName = user.lastName;
          self.user = user;
        });
    }
```

Here is the call to the cloud function

```
export default {
  getCurrentUser() {
    var queryUser = Firebase.functions().httpsCallable('me');
    return queryUser().then(result => {
      **console.log("returnedData: ", result.data);**
      return result.data;
    });
  };
};
```

This is the page that calls the profile page

```js
<template>
  <b-card id="dashboardContainer" no-body>
    <b-tabs card v-on:input="tabBecameVisible">
      <b-tab title="Matches">
        <MentorMatchChart ref="matchChart" />
      </b-tab>
      <b-tab title="My profile">
        <MentorProfile ref="profileChart"/>
      </b-tab>

    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
</template>

<script>
  // import API from "../../API.js";
  import LoadingScreen from "../../components/LoadingScreen";
  import MentorProfile from "./Profile";
  import MentorMatchChart from "./Matches";
  export default {
    name: "MentorDashboard",
    components: {LoadingScreen
    , MentorMatchChart
    , MentorProfile
    },
    methods: {
      tabBecameVisible(index) {
        switch(index) {
          case 0: this.$refs.matchChart.setup();
            break;
          case 1: 
      // this.$refs.profileChart.setup();
          MentorProfile.setup();
          default: break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

In the browser, I now see the three console.log messages, which shows that the data is being returned from the cloud function. Yet, I'm still not binding the data to the input fields correctly. Can you please tell me what I'm missing?
[Browser Results with console log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEqKM.png)
Any way I do this, the firstName displayed is either blank, or whatever I put in the data() function for the default value (like firstName: "test")

Comment: `console.log(user.lastName);` what is the value you're getting?

Comment: I only put the entire user object in the console.log statement, and I see all elements. The portion for last name is correct ("lastName: 'ReesMentor')

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm only seeing the console.log statement that is inside of the cloud function. Where would I see console.log output when the statement is outside of the cloud function?

Comment: If you can able to create a small demo, that would enable us to help you better

Comment: I was going to include the entire file, but the question posting format has changed, and it encouraged me NOT to include the entire file. What would you like to see? Actual screen shots? The entire file? All related files? (this calls a method in API.js, which calls the cloud function).

Comment: Demo would better but In the meanwhile you can aadd API.js where you have used cloud function

Comment: I have added the api call to the cloud function. I don't understand how to set up a demo. I cannot give you access to the site I am working on. I have no way of setting up a GTM. Are you asking for screen shots?

Comment: I tried to BOLD the console.log statements, but that didn't work.They are: console.log("In Setup", this); and console.log("results:", user.lastName); (in Setup() method),  and then one more in my API.js console.log("returnedData: ", result.data);

Comment: @varit05 What do you mean by demo? To me that means setting up the exact situation for you to look at. A new firebase app, a new firestore database, user accounts, etc.. This would ultimately be the same as the code bits and the one image showing that the data is being returned from the cloud function. I also don't have the resources to duplicate this site, nor do I have permission to do so.